# Assigning id attribute to li doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two UL on my page. UL1 and UL2. Both are Sortable and draggable. When LI from UL1 is added to UL2, the LI is move out of UL1. In order to remove from the UL2, user click on a delete link inside of the LI. The logic is remove the item, and add it back to the UL1 from UL2.

This is my code:

```
$(".xOut").on("click", function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({

            url: '@Url.Action("RemoveCommand")',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                aid: id,
                bId: @(Model.Id)
            },
            success: function(event, ui){
                var newListItem = $("<li />", {
                    html: $("#"+id).html()
                });

                $(newListItem).attr("id", id);

                newListItem.appendTo("#sortable1");
                $("#"+id).remove();
            }
        });
    });
```

**Code work fine if I don't add this line:**

```
$(newListItem).attr("id", id);
```

I need the new item to had an id, and cannot work without it.

How can make this work?

Update Added HTML CODE:

```
<ul id="sortable1" class='droptrue'>
 @for (var i = 0; i < Model.SomeList.Count(); i++)
 {
     var item = @Model.SomeList.ElementAtOrDefault(i);
     if (item != null)
     { 
        <li id="@(item.Id)">
           <div>@item.Name</div>
       </li>
     }
 }
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class='droptrue'>
     @for (var i = 0; i < Model.SomeAssignedList.Count(); i++)
     {
         var item = @Model.SomeAssignedList.ElementAtOrDefault(i);
         if (item != null)
         { 
            <li id="@(item.Id)">
           <div>@item.Name</div>
           </li>
         }
     }
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating a new item and removing the old item, just move it:

```
$(".xOut").on("click", function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("RemoveCommand")',
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      aid: id,
      bId: @(Model.Id)
    },
    success: function(event, ui){
      $("#sortable1").append($("#"+id));
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this involves an ajax call, but anyway -- why don't you remove the old item *before* you add the new one with the **same id**?

Comment: It would be the same, because jQuery supports multiple elements with the same `id`.

Comment: My point was that in the original code, a new element with that id is created and appended somewhere, *then* remove() is called on that id, presumably removing both the old and new element ;)